# Pandas, combination of values and check if any of the combiantions is in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations

I have a `df1` with some `item_id`'s and some values for each item (called "nodes"):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'item_id':['1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3'],'nodes':['a','b','c','d','a','e','f','g']})
```

and a `df2` that is a list of "vectors" where each row is a tuple of nodes (that can be in `df1`, but some of them aren't):

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'vectors':[('a','b'),('b','c'),('d','f'),('e','b')]})
```

I need to count the number of different `item_id`'s in `df1` that have at least one vector in `df2`, given the fact that a vector can be constructed from all possible combiantions of nodes for that item.

For example, `item_id = 1` have the nodes `[a,b,c]`, so these vectors can be formed: `[(a,b),(a,c),(b,a),(b,c),(c,a),(c,b)]`. Since the vectors `(a,b)` and `(b,c)` exist in `df2`, then I should count `item_id = 1`. However, I should not count `item_id = 2` since from all the vectors that can be formed from the combination of its nodes, none of them is in `df2`.

I don't know how can I achieve that. I can obtain a list of all possible combinations of nodes to form the different vectors for the first `item_id` in `df1`, using:

```
from itertools import product
nodes_fa=df1[df1.item_id=="1"].nodes.to_list()
vectors_fa = pd.DataFrame(product(nodes_fa,nodes_fa),columns=['u','v'],dtype='str')
vectors_fa['vector'] = vectors_fa[["u", "v"]].agg(tuple, axis=1)
vectors_fa = vectors_fa[['vector']]
display(vectors_fa)
```

but I don't know how to expand this to all the `item_id`'s, nor how to check if any value in this list is in `df2` inside a loop.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), with help of `set`/`frozenset`:

To consider the edges undirected (`('a', 'b')` == `('b', 'a')`):

```
from itertools import combinations

S = set(frozenset(x) for x in df2['vectors'])

out = (
 df1.groupby('item_id')['nodes']
    .apply(lambda g: any(frozenset(t) in S for t in combinations(g, r=2)))
    .sum()
)
```

For directed edges (`('a', 'b')` != `('b', 'a')`):

```
from itertools import combinations

S = set(df2['vectors'])

out = (
 df1.groupby('item_id')['nodes']
    .apply(lambda g: any(t in S for t in combinations(g, r=2)))
    .sum()
)
```

Output: `1`

Alternative with pandas functions (likely less efficient):

```
s = (df1.groupby('item_id')['nodes']
        .agg(lambda g: list(combinations(g, r=2)))
        .explode()
     )

out = s.isin(df2['vectors']).groupby(level=0).any().sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose a solution using merges instead of relying on `apply`
Depending on how many `item_id` values exist, and how many rows for each `item_id`, it might be preferable for performance as well.

```
merged_df1 = pd.merge(df1, df1, left_on='item_id', right_on='item_id')
#eliminates the (x,y) pairs where x == y. Remove if this is not the intended behavior
merged_df1 =  merged_df1[merged_df1['nodes_x'] != merged_df1['nodes_y']]

#splitting tuples of df2 into 2 columns
df2[['node_1', 'node_2']] = pd.DataFrame(df2.vectors.tolist())
valid_id = pd.merge(merged_df1, df2, 
                    left_on=['nodes_x','nodes_y'], 
                    right_on=['node_1', 'node_2']
                    ).item_id.unique()
out = len(valid_id)
```